# Fitting regression where data is concentrated at the origin

Tags: regression, residuals, generalized-additive-model, polynomial, intercept

I'm doing an exploratory data analysis which is looking at a number of character-level features of Chinese writing. The association I am looking at currently is that between the complexity of the character (discrete) and estimated age of acquisition (continuous). The data in its raw form looks like this:

[image]

Based on what I see, it appears the data is first generated closely around the origin, becomes a large ellipsoid that is weakly correlated, then tampers off towards the right. Given this information, I considered the following options:

- **Regular OLS**: This just doesn't work. It overpredicts where the data should be by a lot.
- **No-intercept linear model**: Because the data originates close to the origin $[0,0]$ I considered a suppressed intercept, but this seems implausible given its impossible for someone to have an age of zero when acquiring words, and it is likely also impossible to have a complexity score of zero, so I abandoned that idea.
- **GAM**: I used a variety of GAM fittings and the best fit seemed to be an adaptive smooth, but it still seems to overpredict data near the origin. This still generally did the job though in terms of capturing the rest of the distribution.
- **Polynomial regression**: I usually don't like these for nonlinear regression, but this seems to do the best job of capturing the bottom left part of the distribution that I am concerned with. The residual diagnostics seem to be fairly good too. The only issue I see here is that it interpolates somewhat poorly at the right-most side of the regression line.
- **Poisson or beta regression**: The DV can only take on values of 1 or greater. However, because the data is continuous, I don't think it works here. I tried beta regression too (by transforming the data into proportions) and the model just looked wrong.

Below are the four candidate fits which appear to at least get close to reality.

[image]

The residuals from the polynomial fit are shown below. The residuals are obviously banded and cluster more in certain areas, but I think generally they don't look terrible:

[image]

[image]

Does the polynomial regression work best here or is another approach better? I will note that this dataset has thousands of values, so it clusters a lot in the middle of the ellipsoid in the scatterplot.

##### Edit

Filtering for the values closer to the origin (AoA <= 2), the plot looks something like this (with an auto-generated LOESS line):

[image]

##### Edit 2

As for the context: AoA is in single digits and is supposed to be an estimation of when the Chinese *originally* learned a character (it is a subjective self-recall measure). The rating is based off an averaging across subjects for a single character, hence the decimal units. For example, 3 people may recall that they learned 我 when they were 6 years old, 7 years old, and 7 years old respectively, which averages to 6.67ish years. So here it is highly unlikely the age will be higher than typical early childhood years.

As for perimetric complexity, it is *normally* continuous and is formulated as:

$$
\frac{P^2}{A 4 \pi}
$$

where $P$ is the perimeter of the ink space of a character, $A$ is the area, and $\pi$ is just literally $\pi$. But in this dataset it is unfortunately rounded and I can't get back those decimal values. As for the unusualness in the distribution, my major concern was that the center of the distribution is much heavier (there are 3600+ obs here in case that's not clear) so the outsides of the distribution have some fairly uneven weighting of the regression line. I also want to balance model parsimony here, so getting away from an overly complex polynomial would be ideal.

Comment: It seems all characters (in your plot) of age 1 have a very low complexity, how about a separate slope for these?

Comment: Have you looked at OLS on a spline transform of complexity? A 5th order polynomial does not look terrible, that's true, but I would be wary of its variance at the tails of your IV... which is where you are unhappy about straight-up OLS.

Comment: @StephanKolassa do you mean fitting a natural spline into a regular regression? I tried that and it seemed like even slight increases in degrees of freedom made it perform worse than the polynomial version.

Comment: @user2974951 all of the AoA values which are equal to 1 are equal to a complexity of 0, so they are effectively a linear constant when filtered that way.

Comment: What about all which are less than or equal to 1.1?

Comment: This ends up with the same issue.

Comment: I don't get it, from the plot I see that there are at least a couple of values around age 1 with complexity ranging from ~5 to almost 20, yet you are saying they all have a complexity of 0?

Comment: Anything that assumes the data are Gaussian is going to give you issues - as the last plot in your Q shows. You need an estimate and interval that **cannot** go below 1. I might be cheeky and try a Tweedie after subtracting 1 from all values (and remembering to add it back on when comparing observed vs fitted). Using an adaptive smooth looks complete overkill to me; did you do that because you wanted the smooth to be monotonic? If you did, then using shape-constraints would be a better approach; see if the scam package works for you

Comment: *Did you do that because you wanted the smooth to be monotonic*---Yes, I was trying to force the smooth to be less rigid when I was originally fitting splines to the data (see comment above about `ns` splines), though that may not have been totally necessary. Your idea about using the Tweedie and subtraction doesn't sound bad, though I admit I'm less educated on fitting Tweedie models, so I'll have to look into that one.

Comment: A few comments:  1) Given the subject matter, I am guessing AoA is in thousands of years. Whether that is so or not, why is the minimum AoA 1?  Did Chinese stop acquiring characters?  That seems impossible.   2) The shape of your scatter plot really doesn't look that unusual to me. "A large ellipsoid tapering off ...." sounds like most scatter plots I see.  3) Of course a degree 5 polynomial fits better than a straight line, but how much better? And is that degree 5 polynomial interpretable?  4) Is complexity really discrete? If so, it takes one heck of a lot of values!

Comment: I've edited for extra clarity.

Comment: Do I read this correctly that you are looking at recollections of what people knew at ages 1 to 7 years old? If so, what independent checks do you have? I don't trust anybody's recollections of what they knew about when they were 1 year old, let alone fine distinctions about which character was familiar before or after which other character.

Comment: You might be right about that. Typically I usually only deal with directly measurable objective scales. AoA is sometimes measured using corpus or curriculum-based tracking, which is more ideal, but thats unfortunately not available here. I'm not as familiar with what is usually best practice with using subjective scales so perhaps I should educate myself on that a bit before launching into an analysis. Your commentary at least makes logical sense to me.

Comment: I don't speak or read Chinese -- so I should stop there. But trying the closest analogue for someone whose first language is English I would just be guessing wildly on what age I knew almost all words.  And -- since this is about written language -- reported ages 1 and 2 really seem implausible to me.

Comment: No, that makes complete sense, probably moreso for Chinese. I'm glad I had this discussion here. I hadn't carefully considered this variable enough, and probably should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nick posited, it seems somewhat implausible to use the age of acquisition measure unless there are raters who can independently verify the veracity of these ratings in some way. While there are more directly measurable corpus/curriculum-based measures of AoA, that is unfortunately unavailable in this dataset. It just stands to reason that guessing the age when you learned thousands of Chinese characters is probably not the best way of measuring this idea.

Having considered the commentary in this question, I have come to the conclusion that the age of acquisition measurement method in this study is perhaps *too subjective* to pursue further, and it is probably not reasonable to fit a model with at as a DV, so I won't pursue that particular part of the analysis further. Thankfully, there are other avenues I was already going to pursue with other parts of this data, so I will pursue them instead.

As for the original intent of this question, I suppose the answer to this question is somewhere in between what Peter and Gavin suggested. A parsimonious model that fits the distributional bounds here (perhaps with something like a rigged up Tweedie model) would be more ideal. Perhaps that is not an option here anymore, but something to consider in a future analysis.